# Where is Xcode 4.3.2 installed?

Tags: xcode4.3

I downloaded xcode_432_lion.dmg from iOS developer site. I double clicked it and went through an installer. This seems to mount the .dmg file as a volume. The Xcode.app is available from tho virtual device. Has anyone else seen this behavior? How can I run Xcode from a normal hard drive device? This whole thing is very confusing to me and I haven't seen any install guide.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here is the answer for others clueless like me. To install Xcode 4.3.2, double click the .dmg file. Then drag the Xcode icon and drop it somewhere on the hard drive, preferably on the /Applications folder.

What I was doing before was running Xcode directly from within the .dmg file (which is mounted as a device by OS X).

Answer (score 0):

Check your home directory, there should be a folder called Developer that's where XCode is installed.

Comment: I do not have a Developer folder under home. I have updated my question with a screenshot of the Xcode.app file. As you can see it is in the /Volumes/Xcode folder which is basically a mount of the xcode_432_lion.dmg file.